# cannot delete from specified table - MS Access (DELETE with LEFT JOIN query)

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, left-join, sql-delete

when I run the query below, I get the message "cannot delete from specified tables".  Works fine when I change the DELETE to SELECT. Appreciate any guidance

```
DELETE DISTINCTROW a.*, b.*
FROM everything AS a
LEFT JOIN [YTD Leavers] AS b
    ON val(a.[lookup_number]) = val(b.[Employee Number])
WHERE b.[employee number] IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Please note that the access tag says "DO NOT USE this tag"

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `DELETE` with `DISTINCTROW`, as the error message is telling you.  Instead, you can rephrase your delete query using a `WHERE EXISTS` clause:

```
DELETE everything.*
FROM everything
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM [YTD Leavers]
    WHERE val([YTD Leavers].[Employee Number]) = val(everything.[lookup_number])
) = TRUE
```